# Как добавить кнопку на панель при клике мыши в Java?

Tags: java, swing, mouse-event

В общем. Стоит такая задача. Создать пустое окно.После клика мыши должна появиться кнопка на месте клика. Количество кнопок должно быть максимум 10.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
      System.out.println(me.getX() + " - " + me.getY());
      if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
      //Добавить кнопку
      }
}
```

Comment: `Swing`? `FX`? Какая технология? Само окно есть уже? Это `JFrame`?

Comment: Сори.Окно JFrame
Кнопка JButton

Comment: *Вариант 2:* перед добавлением получать количество элементов типа "Кнопка" на вашей форме. Ну и добавление п.1

Answer (score 0):

решение "в лоб"

```
    System.out.println(evt.getX() + " - " + evt.getY());
    if (evt.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        return;
    }
    //Считаем количество кнопок на форме
    long count = Arrays.stream(this.getContentPane().getComponents())
            .filter((comp) -> comp instanceof JButton)
            .count();
    if (count >= 10) {
        return;
    }
    JButton button = new JButton("OK");
    button.setBounds(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), 50, 50);
    button.setAlignmentY(evt.getY());
    // button.setSize(25, 25);
    this.add(button);
    this.repaint();
```