# создание кнопки по клику мыши

Tags: java

Вот такое задание

1. Создайте пустое окно.
2. При клике мышью в произвольной точке окна в этом месте должна появиться кнопка.
3. Если кнопок будет уже 10 штук, то должно выводиться сообщение через JOptionPane: «Максимум 10 кнопок!»

```java
public class MauseEvent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("добавление кнопки по клику мыши");
        frame.setBounds(0,0,500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel a = new JPanel(); //создаем панель

        a.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
        JButton q = new JButton("кнопка ");// создаем кнопку

        frame.add(a); // добавляем панель на окно
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {  // отслеживаем действие кнопки мыши
        int count = 1 ; // создаем счетчик кликов
            @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clic");
        if(count > 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," допустимо 10 кнопок");
       }else { JButton q = new JButton("кнопка " + count);
        frame.add(q);   // добавляем кнопку на панель по клику мыши
        q.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
      }
      }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

      }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

      }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

      }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

      }
    });
   }     
 }
```

У меня кнопки создаются почему то одна вместо другой.

Comment: у тебя ссылка на кнопку "q" при клике меняет значение ссылки на новую (при создание на клике). Если при клику имя сменить на  JButton anotherName = new JButton("кнопка " + count)   то будет два Button'a

Comment: Вы перекрывете одну кнопку другой(setBounds одинаковые). Вот недавно похожий вопрос был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043846/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java/1068040#1068040

Comment: @Jackson750 кнопки создаются нормально. Просто "поверх" друг друга

Comment: a.add(q );   // добавляем кнопку на панель по клику мыши
  q.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(),100,20);     такой вариант позволяет создавать кнопку в том месте где кликнул , но как только кликаешь в другом месте старая кнопка исчезает , возможно ли что бы они все  10 оставались на панеле ?

Comment: Ошибку исправил , все отлично работает - спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо задание решил.